# Iterating over argv[] produces segmentation fault

Tags: c, loops, argv, argc

I'm writing a program that reads "flags" from the command line as well as the program name. I want the program to read several flags (`-i`, `-c` and `-n`) and execute different functions when one or a combination of flags is called.

This is the code I started to write:

```
  printf("Argv 0: %s\n", argv[0]);
  printf("Argv 1: %s\n", argv[1]);
  printf("Argv 2: %s\n", argv[2]);

  for (int i = 1; i <= argc + 1; i++) {
    if (strcmp("-i", argv[i]) == 0) {
      printf("%s\n", "found -i"); 
    }
    else{
      printf("%s\n", "did not find -i");
    }

  }
```

Just experimenting with one flag (`-i`), but I want it the read one or several flags at the same time and it to call the corresponding functions.

When I execute the program:

```
./program-name test -i
Argv 0: test
Argv 1: -i
Argv 2: (null)
found -i
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Not knowing the definition, won't `i <= argc + 1` cause out-of-bounds access?

Comment: @MikeCAT In one word: No. But `strcmp("-i", argv[argc])` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't redo old code that is proven solid.  It wastes time and duplicates effort.  As a long time C coder, I always (when I remember) go and look at code bases for something first before I try to start from scratch. I repurpose first then create. I'm smart enough to know there were lots of smarterer coders that went before me.

Use the free and working getopt() and getopt_long() functions to parse command line arguments for you.  There are lots of examples in code bases if you google search "getopt example"  [but here is the GNU C tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int aflag = 0;
  int bflag = 0;
  char *cvalue = NULL;
  int index;
  int c;

  opterr = 0;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "abc:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'a':
        aflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'b':
        bflag = 1;
        break;
      case 'c':
        cvalue = optarg;
        break;
      case '?':
        if (optopt == 'c')
          fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        else if (isprint (optopt))
          fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        else
          fprintf (stderr,
                   "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                   optopt);
        return 1;
      default:
        abort ();
      }

  printf ("aflag = %d, bflag = %d, cvalue = %s\n",
          aflag, bflag, cvalue);

  for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
    printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! getopt is the way to go! :D

Answer (score 3):

To simplify, `argc` is the count of command line arguments, and the arguments are held in `argv[]`. As C arrays have `0` based indexing, in your code, you need to change

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= argc + 1; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc;  i++)
```

to limit the access to *valid* argument list.

To add a bit of reference to this, quoting `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1, *Program startup* (*emphasis mine*)

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by **`argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters**.

Comment: Sure? Cf. my comment above.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider well, from that point of view, `argv[argc]` is not a _valid_ "program parameter". (note the use of _valid_)

Comment: And to further quote from the same location ;-): **argv[argc] shall be a null pointer.** Not a valid param though, true.

Comment: Just want to point out, that the OP's `for` loop is *off by* ***two***.

Answer (score 1):

You're overrunning the bounds of `argv`; the condition of your `for` loop is incorrect. It should be `i < argc`.

Also, why reinvent the wheel? Look into `getopt()`.

Comment: I do not think that is correct. argv[argc] is valid (its value is always null) -- and that's the reason why *dereferencing* it fails.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider `i < argc` does not include `argv[argc]`.

Comment: @i486 Exactly. The OP's loop is correct, but redundant. He must test argv[i] for null and not dereference it if it is (which is the case for argv[argc].

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I don't get your point. The program's arguments are from `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]`. Since `argv[1]` is the program's invocation name, the sane thing to do would be set up a loop that iterates from `1` to `argc - 1` inclusive.

Comment: (I think you wanted to say " Since argv[**0**] is the program's invocation name".) You are right, the loop should sensibly only run to argc-1. But the expression `argv[argc]` is valid to use in expressions and is not at all "overrunning the bounds of `argv`". `argv` is long enough and has indeed `argc+1` elements.It's just that the last element, `argv[argc]`, is null, so that `*argv[argc]`, which `strcmp` performs, tries to dereference a null pointer, and consequently crashes on a system with memory protection.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Fair enough. But even with `NULL` check, the OP is *still* overrunning `argv` because the limit of his `for` loop is `i <= argc + 1`, which means that `argv[argc+1]` would be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

With your code and your loop, this line is wrong :

```
(strcmp("-i", argv[i])
```

You should ensure that argv[i] is not NULL when you pass it to strcmp. The function is known to segfault with a NULL pointer as an argument. You should better test if argv[i] != NULL or put i <= argc in your loop instead of i <= argc + 1 which include the NULL pointer in the argv array of strings.